# Forcing the end of a while-Loop prematurely ONLY when an (IF) loop is incorporated into the while loop?

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop, c++14

The program is supposed to ask the input to input a variable for a vector UNTIL the user picks "-0" to stop the while loop.
WITH THIS "IF" nested loop within the While loop, it allows 3 entries before it stops the program! why?
Please find the "THIS RIGHT HERE; THIS is the offending code!" note in this codeblock and try the program **with or without** said 'if' statement.

```
   int main(){
    std::vector<float> asdf;
    float g = 0; std::cout << "enter value g;" << endl;
    std::cin >> g; asdf.push_back(g);
    while (g != -0) {
        std::cout << "enter another g value" << endl;
        std::cin >> g;
        asdf.push_back(g);
    /* **THIS RIGHT HERE; THIS is the offending code!** */       if (g = -0) { asdf.pop_back(); }
    }   
    std::cout << "end of vector" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < asdf.size(); i++) { std::cout << asdf[i] << ", "; }
    std::cout << "end of while;" << endl;
    system("pause"); return 0;
    
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I have to ask: what was your reasoning in (attempting to) compare with *negative* zero?

Comment: In `if (g = -0)`, `=` is used for assignment whereas `==` is used for comparison

Comment: Is `g = -0` a typo? Because you just set g equal -0 by yourself

Comment: [Turn on compiler warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/17ecc3) and your compiler should warn you about this.

Comment: @TechGeek49: `g` is `float` so on most systems there is such a thing as minus zero, different from zero, but writing `-0` won't produce it (since `0` is `int`); you have to write `-0.0`.  It's not clear if that's what OP really wants, of course.

Comment: Oh I ain't aware that it's a `float`

Comment: In C++, 0.0 is equal to -0.0. If you really want to test negative zero, you would have to write something like `if (g == 0.0 && std::signbit(g)) { /* negative 0.0 */ }`.

Comment: Because of all the subtilities related to negative 0, it would be preferable to avoid it to avoid confusion both for user and code maintainer. One has to be aware of required decimal point and the use of `signbit` which many people are not aware including OP himself!

Comment: You should likely just ask the user for a string input. If they enter `exit` (or empty string or whatever you like) then you're done, otherwise parse the string as a float (and handle errors). Also, you'll get kicked out of programming school with variable names like `asdf`.